# How can I designate lines of code for Clover to ignore?

Tags: junit, code-coverage, clover, test-coverage

I would like to tell Clover to ignore particular lines of my Java code.
Is there any way to do so from within the code?

Something like

```
//// IGNORE vvvvvvv
System.out.println("Ignore this line and considered it covered");
//// IGNORE ^^^^^^^
```

If not, is there a clean way to do so by providing a context descriptor from outside the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use:

```
//CLOVER:OFF
//CLOVER:ON
```

[Here's](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Using+Source+Directives) official doc about it